# How do I write an AREL UpdateManager query for MySQL that uses a subquery

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel

I am tying to run an update query with a subquery against a MySQL database using ruby.  I am using ruby 1.9.3 and rails 4.1.

The query I am trying to create is as below:

```
 UPDATE `items` 
 SET 
     `items`.`status_id` = 12
 WHERE
     `items`.`id` IN (SELECT DISTINCT
             `items`.`id`
         FROM
             `items`
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN
             `statuses` ON `items`.`status_id` = `statuses`.`id`
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN
             `resources` ON `items`.`resource_id` = `resources`.`id`
         WHERE
             `statuses`.`title` LIKE 'On Loan'
                 AND `items`.`duedate` < '2015-04-24'
                 AND `items`.`return_date` IS NULL
         ORDER BY `items`.`duedate`)
```

I can produce this query in ruby using AREL with the code shown below:

```
# Declare Arel objects
i = Item.arel_table
s = Status.arel_table
r = Resource.arel_table

# This is the AREL query that returns the data
overdues = i.project(i[:id]).
join(s, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).on(i[:status_id].eq(s[:id])).
join(r, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).on(i[:resource_id].eq(r[:id])).
where(s[:title].matches("On Loan").
  and(i[:duedate].lt(DateTime.now.to_date)).
  and(i[:return_date].eq(nil))
  ).
order(i[:duedate])

# Note: You can't chain distinct, otherwise "overdues" becomes a string with the value "DISTINCT".
overdues.distinct

# This creates the update...
u = Arel::UpdateManager.new i.engine
u.table(i)
u.set([[i[:status_id], 10]]).where(i[:id].in(overdues))
```

This does not work and returns an error message:

*ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You can't specify target table 'items' for update in FROM clause:*

I tried using AR "update_all" but it produces the same SQL and hence the same error.

```
Item.where(i[:id].in(overdues)).update_all(:status_id => (Status.find_by(:title => "Overdue").id))
```

Having done some research I have found that you cannot run a update with a subquery that references the table you want to update in MySQL.  I have seen a number of posts on this site and the wider internet that detail work arounds.

One suggestion says that the update should use a join instead of a sub query.  Having looked at the code behind the update manager it has no "join" so I can't do that.

Another says run this in two parts but I can't see how to because AREL and AciveRecord both chain actions.

The only way I can see of doing this is by aliasing the table and adding an additional select (see below).  This isn't great but it would be useful to see if it is possible to do.

```
UPDATE `items` 
SET `status_id` = 10 
WHERE `items`.`id` IN (
  SELECT x.id 
  FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT `items`.`id` 
      FROM `items` 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN `statuses` ON `items`.`status_id` = `statuses`.`id` 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN `resources` ON `items`.`resource_id` = `resources`.`id` 
      WHERE `statuses`.`title` LIKE 'On Loan' 
      AND `items`.`duedate` < '2015-04-24' 
      AND `items`.`return_date` IS NULL  
      ORDER BY `items`.`duedate`) x
);
```

If I can't get this to work I could adopt two other approaches:

1) I could just hard-code the SQL but I want to use ActiveRecord and reference the models to keep it database agnostic.

2) The other way is to return an instance of all the records and loop through them doing individual updates.  This will have a performance issue but I can accept this because its a background job that won't be updating more than a handful of records each day.

**Update**

I have the AREL query below that produces the subquery in the format I need.

```
x = Arel::Table.new('x')

overdues = Item.select(x[:id]).from(
Item.select(Item.arel_table[:id]).where(
    Status.arel_table[:title].matches("On Loan").and(
    Item.arel_table[:duedate].lt(DateTime.now.to_date).and(
    Item.arel_table[:return_date].eq(nil))
    )
  ).joins(
    Item.arel_table.join(Status.arel_table, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).on(
      Item.arel_table[:status_id].eq(Status.arel_table[:id])
    ).join_sources
  ).joins(
    Item.arel_table.join(Resource.arel_table, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).on(
      Item.arel_table[:resource_id].eq(Resource.arel_table[:id])
    ).join_sources
  ).order(Item.arel_table[:duedate]).uniq.as('x')
)
```

Sadly it returns an error when I use it in my update statement.

```
TypeError: Cannot visit Item::ActiveRecord_Relation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having revisited this question I am at the conclusion that it's not possible to do this because of a limitation with MySQL:

*ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You can't specify target table 'items' for update in FROM clause:*

It should be possible to do with other databases (although I haven't tested that).

I could create a temporary table, which is the copy of the original table, reference that and then drop the temporary table like this post suggests: 
http://richtextblog.blogspot.co.uk/2007/09/mysql-temporary-tables-and-rails.html.  That seems a lot of overhead to do a simple subquery.

What I am going to do is find all the ID's and loop through them and update the records that way (using a simple find and update).  This has an overhead but it should only be updating a handful of records each run (no more than 100).  The update will be running as a scheduled job outside user working hours so it won't impact performance.

I still find it bizarre that in all other flavours of SQL I have never encountered this problem before.  Still you live and learn.

**UPDATE:**
Since updating my version of MySQL the select statement now works.  I had to take out the order by for it to work.

```
ORDER BY `items`.`duedate`
```

I am now using version: 5.7.19.